# Get offsetLeft on mousemove

Tags: elm

In js, when handling event with `addEventListener('mousemove',handler)`, inside the `handler`, we get access to the `this` which holds reference to the dom element, which has important properties like `offsetLeft`.

How do I decode the `this` object in elm so i can get those properties?

Comment: I think getting a state/value from DOM is not a Elm way.  I think you should try to put it in your model and build DOM from the model.  Event handler is used to obtain user action, not the DOM state.

Comment: How do you put offsetLeft inside the model? Better yet, how do you put the browser width into the model : )

Comment: I would use `port` to react with browser events.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you get back from http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-Events#onMouseUp but that might be enough

Otherwise you build your own event handler as follows:

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.1.0/Html-Events#on

```
onMouseMove : msg -> Attribute msg
onMouseMove message =
  on "mousemove" (Json.map message (Json.at ["offsetLeft"] Json.int))
  -- on "mousemove" (Json.map message (Json.at ["target", "offsetLeft"] Json.int))
```

Comment: I was aware of the `target` property inside the js event object, but unfortunately it is a reference to the dom element that captured the event, not the one that listens to it. I need a reference to the element that listens to that event, which is `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this package, http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-dom/1.2.1/

It gives you to access the DOM properties in event handlers.